# Getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ec2-ip/login

Tags: python, reactjs, nginx, flask, cors

I have a react frontend which is deployed on S3. Now I have mapped my domain with the S3 hosted url. So whenever someone tries to access s3 hosted url, they will get redirected to https://myproject.mycompany.com . My backend is using Flask python, which is in Ec2(Ubuntu instance). I am using Nginx(reverse proxy) and gunicorn as well. I have done Nginx conf setup, flask-cors setup.

Whenever I’m trying to make a login request to my backend, the request doesn’t reach Nginx. Surprisingly when I try to make an http request it works well, but not https request.
I get below error when I try to make request

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://ec2-ip/login. (Reason: CORS
> request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Any idea how this can be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use withCredentials if you used axios you can set defaults in App.js file. I mean you have to send your request from front to backend by withCredentials= true

```
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

then in your setting.py change to this :

```
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

  CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

  CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

  CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
   'https://ec2-ip/login',
   'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'your frontend local host url'
  ]
```

Comment: hi @tanmay AK  i am using fetch at frontend. I tried doing this but it didn't work. Got the same error. Seems like the certificate i used while setting up nginx is not authorised and causing the issue. I created certificate and key using openssl. I am not able to create certificate and key using certbot. Any idea how i can do that ?

Comment: is working without nginx? i think at first you have to be sure your connection between front and backend is ok? then you try use of ngnix and check the setting of nginx.

Comment: `https://ec2-ip/login` is not a valid Web-origin value: [Web origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) don't contain a path.