# CORS Filter issue while using react (client) with springboot (server) in intellij , im using springboot 3.1.5 with no spring security involved

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, cors

`error : Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/api/users/signup/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

i tried everything under the sun to resolve the error crossorgins , global cors files , the one im using right now is CorsConfig.java that i placed in the same package as my main springbootapplication root directory.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlQRs.png)

im clueless about what im doing wrong. pls help.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77306322/getting-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-t/77306614#77306614

Answer (score 0):

In your CorsConfig file, try adding configuration.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS"). OPTIONS requests are often used in conjunction with CORS requests to determine whether a cross-origin request is allowed.

Comment: For preflight to succeed, the server must handle `OPTIONS` requests but, contrary to popular belief, listing `OPTIONS` as an allowed method in the CORS configuration is rarely necessary. It's only needed for clients that explicitly use the `OPTIONS` method, e.g. with `fetch("...", {method: "OPTIONS"})`.